# Symfony2 - Redirection after successful login

Tags: authentication, symfony

I've just started working through the Symfony 2 tutorials.  I have created a bundle with a user class and have tried to follow the instructions to set up a login process.  I think I am nearly there, however I'm currently falling at the last hurdle.

I have set up a bundle: Dan\AuthBundle, which contains my user class and another bundle: Dan\HelloBundle which I want to allow only logged in users to access.

My security.yml file is as follows:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Dan\AuthBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: Dan\AuthBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
        administrators:
            entity: { class: DanAuthBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/*
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /hello

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/hello/.* }
```

The main routing.yml file looks like this:

```
DanAuthBundle:
    resource: "@DanAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /auth/

DanHelloBundle_homepage:
pattern:  /hello/
defaults: { _controller: DanHelloBundle:Default:index }

login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: {_controller: DanAuthBundle:Default:login }

login_check:
    pattern: /login_check
```

I have created several instances of my user class manually.

If I try to access the url /hello, I correctly get redirected to the login page.  If I enter incorrect details, I get the correct message(s) delivered in the template, however, when I log in with the correct details, I receive a 324 (empty response) error (at this time, the url displayed in the browser is login_check).

From reading the documentation, I thought I should be redirected to the page I was originally trying to access?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form

> By default, if the submitted credentials are correct, the user will be
>   redirected to the original page that was requested (e.g. /admin/foo).
>   If the user originally went straight to the login page, he'll be
>   redirected to the homepage. This can be highly customized, allowing
>   you to, for example, redirect the user to a specific URL.

Also, if I try to access the page after entering the correct details, I once again get redirected to the login page.

Can anyone see if I've missed anything obvious?

This is from my log file:

> [2012-06-18 18:33:47] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username
>   AS username2, t0.salt AS salt3, t0.hashed_password AS hashed_password4
>   FROM User t0 WHERE t0.username = ? (["hello"]) [] [] [2012-06-18
>   18:33:47] security.INFO: User "hello" has been authenticated
>   successfully [] [] [2012-06-18 18:33:47] event.DEBUG: Listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest" stopped
>   propagation of the event "kernel.request". [] [] [2012-06-18 18:33:47]
>   event.DEBUG: Listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener" was not
>   called for event "kernel.request". [] [] [2012-06-18 18:33:47]
>   event.DEBUG: Listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener" was not
>   called for event "kernel.request". [] [] [2012-06-18 18:33:47]
>   event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse".
>   [] [] [2012-06-18 18:33:47] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in
>   the session [] []

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try to add a login listener to redirect your user : http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/

Comment: Here is also my answer with target_path:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17424321/1866083

Answer (score 7):

```
// if you're using Symfony 2.0
$key = '_security.target_path';
// if you're using Symfony 2.1 or greater
// where "main" is the name of your firewall in security.yml
$key = '_security.main.target_path';

// try to redirect to the last page, or fallback to the homepage
if ($this->container->get('session')->has($key)) {
  $url = $this->container->get('session')->get($key);
  $this->container->get('session')->remove($key);
} else {
  $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('homepage');
}

return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need 2 listeners.

- One to set in session last page
- Second to redirect after succesfull login

That link will solve your problem: http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/

Comment: Hi,  is this something that has changed recently?  I've added the quote from the documentation that made me believe it would redirect automatically.  Is the documentation no longer correct?

Comment: Hi the _target_path is easy solution, but when you need to redirect in other controllers (ex. when user go another role it's useful to have those listeners).

Answer (score -3):

just use getUser check in your respective action (where you are rendering the login form view) as below:

`if($this->getUser()){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your-redirect-path-alise')); 
        }`

Comment: "Never check for the User object to see if they're logged in" from the Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#always-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in